# Is it possible to build AOSP project (Gingerbread) in kubuntu12.04 (xubuntu)?

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, android-source

I work with older releases of Android (Gingerbread 2.3.4). To develop for these versions I use now Ubuntu 10.04. At the same time, I would like to use more recent version: 12.04 or maybe 12.10. It is written [here](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html):

> Building on Ubuntu 12.04 is currently only experimentally supported
>   and is not guaranteed to work on branches other than master.

So here is my question, has anybody tried to build old versions of Android on Ubuntu 12.04? I do not like new unity interface so I also consider xfce or kde. That's why here is the second question, will I have any troubles with building if I change window system?

Comment: Windowing system you choose should have nothing to do with building sources.

Comment: Thanks, I have the same thoughts but I just want to be sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to build Gingerbread on Ubuntu 12.10.

Biggest problem is that Ubuntu 12.10 has newer gcc 4.7, which is very strict.
It is possible to fix it by patching Android source to be compliant with new gcc requirements. However, this can be difficult to do, especially when it involves patching older kernel sources.

You can bypass this by simply installing older gcc 4.4 (which is default version in Ubuntu 10.10).

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.4-multilib g++-4.4-multilib
```

After that, you need to make gcc 4.4 to be the default compiler for your Android compilation.
Easiest way is to simply symlink gcc, g++, cpp to point to older versions and add it to PATH:

```
mkdir ~/bin
cd ~/bin
ln -s /usr/bin/g++-4.4 g++
ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.4 gcc
ln -s /usr/bin/cpp-4.4 cpp
# you might want to add line below to ~/.bashrc:
export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Now, you need to have Java installed. Unlike newer Android 4, Gingerbread can be built using OpenJDK, so you should be able to simply

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

to get working JDK.

Also see [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ppcdroid/mmw4xtxJ3wQ/2127u5P8E0EJ).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll use it when I migrate to a new platform )

Comment: Applicable for ICS 4.0.4 as well.

Comment: I installed Kubuntu 12.04, and following your instructions I made build environment. Today I tried to build the latest version of AOSP in this environment. 6 hours passed and I did not manage to finish the built (although on Ubuntu 10.04 it takes about 2-2.5 hours). The problem I see is that the building of c++ files is very slow (it takes about 2 sec to build one cpp file of ~100 LOC). Maybe you know what is the problem or how I can find the reason why it is so slow? If not I'll try to ask another question.

Comment: How much memory do you have? If you are building Android 4.x, minimal memory required is 8GB, and 16GB is recommended. Also, your `make -jN` command should have N no bigger than number of cores (output of `nproc`), and no bigger than amount of memory in GB (one thread takes 1GB). For i7 and 8GB+ RAM good value is `8`. If you do not use `-j`, your build will be very slow.