# how to specify the use of g++ in Android.mk?

Tags: android, c++, g++, android-source

I have a c++ library that i've added to the android2.3.6 source code and i want to **compile it and link** using g++ instead of gcc and ld.
is it possible?
Also,i've added this line into my Android.mk file:

```
  LOCAL_CXX=path/to/g++compiler
```

But the building still use gcc.

is there any solution?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Full Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir) 
libdash_src_files :=cppfiles 
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES :=headers 
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += path_to/stlport 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(libdash_src_files) 

include external/stlport/libstlport.mk 

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libstlport libz LOCAL_SYSTEM_SHARED_LIBRARIES :=libdl libutils libc 

LOCAL_LDLIBS := $(LOCAL_LDLIBS) -llog 

LOCAL_LDFLAGS:= -lz -Wl -shared 

LOCAL_CXX := $(CXX) 
libdash_cppflags :=-g -fPIC -v -frtti -fexceptions 

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS :=$(libdash_cppflags) -fpermissive -w 
LOCAL_MODULE :=libdash 
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS :=optional 
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Where did you see the "building still use gcc"?

Comment: when compiling i got these messages:
End of search list.
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.4.3 (arm-linux-androideabi)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.6.x-google 20120106 (prerelease), GMP version 5.0.5, MPFR version 2.4.1.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: c4d888e5a360c62eda5c2541802f65ce

Comment: Then can you post your full Android.mk file?

Comment: LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
libdash_src_files :=cppfiles
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES :=headers
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += path_to/stlport
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(libdash_src_files)
include external/stlport/libstlport.mk
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libstlport libz
LOCAL_SYSTEM_SHARED_LIBRARIES :=libdl libutils libc
LOCAL_LDLIBS := $(LOCAL_LDLIBS) -llog
LOCAL_LDFLAGS:= -lz -Wl -shared
LOCAL_CXX := $(CXX)
libdash_cppflags :=-g -fPIC -v -frtti -fexceptions
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS :=$(libdash_cppflags) -fpermissive -w
LOCAL_MODULE :=libdash
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS :=optional
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

Comment: Why did you include $(CLEAR_VARS) after setting two vars?

Comment: In general, BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY will use g++, not gcc. Can you use "m/mm/mmm libdash show command" to determine the exact compiler used in your compilation? Moreover, the LOCAL_CPPFLAGS is useless, the BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY won't use that variable.

Comment: Try to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365348/is-it-possible-to-build-aosp-project-gingerbread-in-kubuntu12-04-xubuntu Maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just followed jermaine indications and  did a make clean 
then build it again and it worked fine.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Can you make a better description on how you solve this problem, and accept it as an answer?

Comment: i've just simply moved the place of the $(CLEAR_VARS) just under LOCAL path.and somehow it seems that my previous attempts to build the aosp have disturbed the build of my library .i just decided to do make clean and start all over again the build took me over 2h30 min to finich successfully.and that's all i've done.
thanks a lot Jermaine